# Can a Jewish owned business sponsor (or own) a non-Jewish football team?

Tags: halacha, business, sport-athletics

In recent years, big businesses (including the airlines Emirates, Etihad and Qatar) and wealthy people (including Sheik Mansour) from UAE and Qatar have been sponsoring or purchasing some of the biggest teams in European football: Arsenal, Manchester United, Real Madrid, Olympicacus, Hamburger, AC Milan, Barcelona and Malaga.  Young people are easily influenced by their sports heroes and so many European youth are exposed to their favorite stars wearing "Fly Emirates" kits (aka uniforms.) Arsenal fans (my favorite team) are not only exposed to the Fly Emirates kit, they also watch the team play at Emirates Stadium in North London!

Several articles I have read suggest that these acquisitions and sponsorships are an attempt to create a positive attitude towards Arabs and Muslims. My question is, are there any halakhic reasons why an Israeli (especially a Jewish owned) corporation could not sponsor a European team? (The teams play on Shabbat, etc.) El Al, Bank Leumi, Ahava and Sabra are several companies that come to mind. My ulterior motive would be the same as above; that by doing so, it could  shed Israel in a positive light. Israel, after all, does not have the best PR. Kids (Jewish and Non-Jewish) would see their heroes wearing "Fly El Al" while watching the game at Macabbe Stadium in Manchester!

Comment: @ypnypn Thank you. Those tags are better. Exactly what I intended.

Comment: @ypnypn I just noticed you changed the header. There are and have been a number of Jewish owners in the English Premier League. I am primarily interested in sponsorship.

Comment: Rabbi Yossel Gutnick owned an Australian football team at one point.

Comment: @user3949142. Thanks, I didn't know that. So the same halakhic principles would apply as in any business owned by a Jew that operates on Shabbat? Would it still be allowed in the case of a Jewish owned corporate sponsor (not a team owner) whose advertising would be plastered across the players jerseys?

Comment: I never said any halachik principle.

Comment: I stand corrected @user3949142

Comment: In the US, there are many sports teams owned by Jews.  The Washington Nationals (a baseball team) for example are owned by Jews, and they served kosher for Pesach food to me in the owners box.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen. Thank you Ze'ev for your comment. I am aware of many teams owned by Jews. My main point was that many of the most popular football teams in Europe are sponsored by companies owned by Muslims. Children look up to their heroes and are exposed to "Etihad" "Fly Emirates" etc. on their favorites jersey. Some sources even claim that is the intent; to suade  Europeans to a more friendly attitude of Islam. There are Jewish owners of clubs for sure but no Jewish owned business sponsors a team. I was wondering if the fact that nearly half of the games are played on Shabbat may have........

Comment: ......something to do with that. For example, would it be problematic for El Al to sponsor a team which plays about half of their games on the Sabbath. Would that fact be a cause for the Cheif Rabbinate to, say, withhold Kashrut certification (or take similar action)against El Al? Jewish children may watch a Saturday games and assume it's okay, Afterall, El Al or Ahava or Sabra, etc. is sponsoring the team.

Comment: Ze'ev, ultimately I think it would be a great idea that Israeli (or other obviously Jewish owned) businesses would sponsor a team. Exactly for the same reason the Arab owned companies sponsor; positive influence and public relations. TO CLARIFY: Sponsorship in this context means a company pays a fee to the team to have their company logo on the team's Jersey. They pay a handsome sum for what is essentially advertising. Sponsorships are typically long-term. Obviously it generates enough customers to make it worthwhile.